# How can I install the dropbox python client while disconnected from the internet

Tags: installation, python, dropbox

Okay, I realize this is crazy, but I need to be able to install the python client modules while disconnected from the internet. The devices I'm installing to will eventually be on the internet, but everything I've seen on how to install seems to require "pip install dropbox" which then gives:

"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connection=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror((-2, 'Name or service not known'))': /simple/requests/"

That would figure, the device doesn't have internet yet. I don't have the option of connecting the device, then installing ... sigh.

I figure it must be just getting the correct script files or compiled scripts in the right places.

It's times like this that I *really* like eclipse distros that you just copy the whole thing into a directory and *wham* it is done. :-)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429168) SO answer. Using `pip install <pkg-name> —no-index —find-links file://<path-to-install-files>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use "pip download " on a computer with internet connection to download any package you need, then uplaod to the disconected computer, see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/